# Define bash aliases to run git as specific user

Tags: bash, git, alias, git-config

Is it possible to define a function in a bash script which generically defines git-aliases for different users in order to let users apply their changes on a shared system so that the commits contains their username and email?

```
alias git_as_user1='GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="User1_pre User1_sur" GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="user1@company.de" GIT_SSH="/home/account/ssh_user_wrapper.sh" GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL git'
```

I came up with the following function, but it does not evaluate args at the time of the alias definition but later on, when the alias is called.
This is unintended and renders the approach useless.

```
function alias_git_as ()
{
  alias git_as_$1='GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$1 GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$2
}
```

In .basrc:

```
alias_git_as "login" "Surname Prename" "user@company.de"
```

-> Won't work !!! -> Defines the alias `git_as_login`, but the second and third arg are dismissed. When a certain user runs `git_as_login` from his terminal he would need to pass "Surname Prename" "user@company.de" again. But the args should be captured at time the alias is defined.

Comment: Your code is only wrong because of the quotes. You need to use _double_ quotes, not single quotes, for expansions to take place.

Comment: `alias_git_as() { alias "git_as_$1=GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$2 GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$3"; }`

Comment: BTW, removing the `function` keyword is deliberate. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete (there are relevant entries in two separate tables)

Comment: What does »won't work« mean?

Comment: How do you want to use this alias? Call once to change author or use in place of regular `git` command? Because you never call `git`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `alias git_as_$1='GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$2 GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$3` in the o.p.
_What does won't work' mean_? 
> But it does not evaluate args at the time of the alias definition but later on, when the alias is called. This is unintended and renders the approach useless.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in ways that make existing answers no longer make sense. It's fine to fix something after it's pointed out by comments; but once it's fixed in answers, it needs to stay.

Comment: I reverted the question. @knittl: I want to define an alias once for each of a bunch of users so that all the users can run git using `git_as_username ....` on a shared system.

Comment: @avans if your users authenticate with ssh keys, you can put per-key configuration in the `authorized_keys` file and set environment variables per user automatically that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- You use single quotes, but those suppress expansion; to make expansion happen early, you need double quotes instead.
- Your original code only takes two arguments, but your example usage uses three.

Also, to make this work with names with spaces, we use the bash 5.x feature `${var@Q}` below.

```
# define the function
alias_git_as() { alias "git_as_$1=GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=${2@Q} GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=${3@Q}"; }

# use the function
alias_git_as "login" "Surname Prename" "user@company.de"

# use the invoked alias
git_as_login
```

See this working at https://ideone.com/PV09NG

---

A version that's compatible with older versions of bash while still retaining support for unusual author names may instead look like:

```
alias_git_as() {
  local alias_def
  printf -v alias_def 'git_as_%s=GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=%q GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=%q' "$1" "$2" "$3"
  alias "$alias_def"
}
```